# Android Studio generate signed apk NoClassDefFoundError Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurity

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I have searched for this already and the results have been slightly different to what I am looking for. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I've built an Android app which uses cryptography and it works perfectly in debug mode when I test it, however, when I go to generate a signed APK (I've changed the build variants to release and included ProGuard to run) this error occurs:
**NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurity: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurity**

I have checked my JDK under External Libraries and it's using 1.7.0_67 and JceSecurity IS there under the correct package structure. I also have the local_policy and US_export_policy jars under the jre/lib/security too.

Under External Libraries I have:

- < Android API 20 Platform >
- JceSecurity isn't in android.jar > javax.crypto
- < JDK > (C:Program Files...\jdk1.7.0_67)
- JceSecurity is in jce.jar > javax.crypto

Is there a bit of a muddle up here? The JceSecurity class is there so I don't understand why it can't find it. Do I need to add any permissions to the Manifest or change the build.gradle? Also, once this goes to the app store will users have issues with it as they may not have local_policy and US_export_policy jars installed on their machines?
Any ideas people? Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried with different versions of the local_policy and US_export_policy jars and this seems to have done the trick!